# How to search a text and return a block with adding value (UNIX)

Tags: unix, search, sed

Currently I use a "SED "command to return each block of text that contains a word from my pattern list.

Here is the structure of my file* (size of file is around 20Go):

```
BEGIN
blabla
blabla GREAT blabla
END

BEGIN
blabla
blabla
END

BEGIN
blabla USA
blabla
END
```

Here is an extract of my pattern list (around 900 entries)

```
GREAT
USA
...
```

For that i'm using the following command :

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/{x;d};H;/END/{x;s/\(GREAT\|USA\)/&/mp}' myfile.txt>result.txt
```

This command is doing the job, but for further treatment I need to know (for each block) the word of my pattern list that was found. For exemple I would like the following return :

```
BEGIN
blabla
blabla GREAT blabla
Patern=GREAT
END
BEGIN
blabla USA
blabla
Patern=USA
END
```

Do you have any suggestion in order to doing that?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/BEGIN/{x;d};H;/END/{x;s/\(GREAT\|USA\)/&\
patern=\1/m;s/\(END\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/p;}' myfile.txt>result.txt
```

that add the line patern= with the value of your WORD than swap 2 last line before printing

Answer (score 0):

This is a job `awk` can do:

```
awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" 'BEGIN {n=split("USA GREAT",a," ")} {for (i=1;i<=n;i++) if ($0~a[i]) print $0"\nPatern="a[i]}' file
BEGIN
blabla
blabla GREAT blabla
END
Patern=GREAT

BEGIN
blabla USA
blabla
END
Patern=USA
```

It stores all the pattern in array `a` and the number of them in variable `n`
Then it test every block if it contains patter, then print bloc and pattern used.

Comment: @tripleee Ups missed that.  Updated my post.